# Deprecating AdMob Windows Phone 8 SDK - Alternatives?

Tags: windows-phone-8, admob

received an email from Google.

> You are receiving this email because you have an app that is using
>   AdMob Windows Phone 8 SDK. On N‌ovember 1st, we will deprecate the
>   AdMob Windows Phone 8 SDK.

What are alternatives to display advertisements on Windows Phone 8 and above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not supporting Windows 10 / UWP and Not providing update to SDK made sense but deprecating existing SDK is something unexpected from Google. Well (disclaimer: not sure if these providers will be worthy integrating), I have used MS native, AdMob, Inneractive, Smaato, Mobfox and Vserv in past. Though revenue depends on various aspects, AdMob was yielding me 50% of revenue. With AdMob deprecation, I will have to resort to MS Native and Vserv. (The others weren't generating significant revenue to me)

Comment: Thanks will try them. MS Native had very low RPM so migrated to admob now it's also going away!

Answer (score 1):

You have an alternative in the Windows Store, Actually microsoft give is own ad platform working for Mobile & Desktop.

I use it in an app and this is easy to use and the performance are correct.

Here the link of the SDK : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/install-the-microsoft-advertising-libraries

Comment: Initially was on Microsoft advertisement but migrated to Admob due to low RPM. will try that again. Thanks for your comment